# What is the difference between ng-show and ng-if in angular 1.x?

Tags: angularjs-directive

Suppose we have an example like

```
<body ng-controller="SomeCtrl as Ctrl">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Ctrl.checked"></input>
      <div ng-if="Ctrl.checked">Some content</div>
</body>
```

and

```
<body ng-controller="SomeCtrl as Ctrl">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Ctrl.checked"></input>
      <div ng-show="Ctrl.checked">Some content</div>
</body>
```

Both ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide achieve the same in the above example. Then why do we have two separate directives for this functionality in angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngIf removes the elements from the DOM, ngShow keeps it but hides it from view:

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf:

**The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.**

Comment: Thanks for clearing the concept. I would read the documentation next time thoroughly next time before asking a question:)